# Angular.js How to change an elements css class on click and to remove all others

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to make my two elements toggle, so if one element is clicked it will remove all references of my-class and apply it to its self. Any ideas?

```
<span id="1" ng-style="my-class" ng-click="tog=my-class"></span>

<span id="2" ng-style="my-class" ng-click="tog=my-class"></span>
```

Cheers!

Comment: offer an example please.

Comment: provided, forgot to indent it.

Comment: Do you mean it removes the style from all other elements? And then applies the style to itself?

Comment: yep thats what i mean.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Create a scope property called selectedIndex, and an itemClicked function:

```
function MyController ($scope) {
  $scope.collection = ["Item 1", "Item 2"];

  $scope.selectedIndex = 0; // Whatever the default selected index is, use -1 for no selection

  $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
  };
}
```

Then my template would look something like this:

```
<div>
      <span ng-repeat="item in collection"
             ng-class="{ 'selected-class-name': $index == selectedIndex }"
             ng-click="itemClicked($index)"> {{ item }} </span>
</div>
```

Just for reference $index is a magic variable available within ng-repeat directives.

You can use this same sample within a directive and template as well.

Here is a working plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jOO8YdPiSJEaOcayEP1X?p=preview

Comment: Take a look at what I posted, it's similar but uses a directive instead of setting variables in a controller. Also I didn't use $index, but that'd be the best way of doing it if you're using ng-repeat. In my example I don't use ng-repeat, so it's a way to do it if you don't have access to $index.

Comment: Defining UI text in a controller array doesn't seem right to me unless you really are dealing with state.  I'd recommend also looking at the solutions provided by Rastapopulous and DotDotDot.

Answer (score 37):

have you tried with a condition in ng-class like here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/zvLvg/ ?

```
    <span id='1' ng-class='{"myclass":tog==1}' ng-click='tog=1'>span 1</span>
    <span id='2' ng-class='{"myclass":tog==2}' ng-click='tog=2'>span 2</span>
```

Comment: I don't think this would be scalable if you had a 100 elements for instance.

Comment: You said you wanted to toggle 2 elements, next time ask for something scalable ;)

Comment: I like this solution but I can't figure out how to default a selection

Comment: @perrohunter With this solution, you could try by adding `ng-init="tog=<default value>"` either on the first span or the parent container. Also, if you use a controller, you can create your default selection value by doing `$scope.tog=<default value>` which would work aswell

Answer (score 11):

To me it seems like the best solution is to use a directive; there's no need for the controller to know that the view is being updated.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['directives']);

angular.module('directives', []).directive('toggleClass', function () {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span ng-click="localFunction()" ng-class="selected"  ng-transclude></span>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.localFunction = function () {
                scope.model.value = scope.$id;
            };
            scope.$watch('model.value', function () {
                // Is this set to my scope?
                if (scope.model.value === scope.$id) {
                    scope.selected = "active";
                } else {
                    // nope
                    scope.selected = '';
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="model = { value: 'dsf'}"> <span>Click a span... then click another</span>

<br/>
<br/>
<span toggle-class model="model">span1</span>

<br/><span toggle-class model="model">span2</span>

<br/><span toggle-class model="model">span3</span>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
     color:red;
 }
```

I have a fiddle that [demonstrates.](http://jsfiddle.net/CzwhM/3/) The idea is when a directive is clicked, a function is called on the directive that sets a variable to the current scope id. Then each directive also watches the same value. If the scope ID's match, then the current element is set to be active using ng-class.

The reason to use directives, is that you no longer are dependent on a controller. In fact I don't have a controller at all (I do define a variable in the view named "model"). You can then reuse this directive anywhere in your project, not just on one controller.

Comment: can i use this with ng-repeat? greetz

Answer (score 7):

Typically with Angular you would be outputting these spans using the ngRepeat directive and (like in your case) each item would have an id. I know this is not true for all situations but it is typical if requesting data from a backend - objects in an array tend to have unique identifiers.

You can use this id to facilitate the toggling of classes on items in your list (see plunkr or code below).

Using the objects id's can also eliminate the undesirable effect when the $index (described in other answers) is messed up due to sorting in Angular.

Example Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/na0gUec6cdMABK9L6drV

(basically apply the .active-selection class if the person.id is equal to $scope.activeClass - which we set when the user clicks an item.

Hope this helps someone, I've found expressions in ng-class to be very useful!

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people" 
  data-ng-class="{'active-selection': person.id == activeClass}">
    <a data-ng-click="selectPerson(person.id)">
      {{person.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "John",
  }, {
    id: "2",
    name: "Lucy"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    name: "Mark"
  }, {
    id: "4",
    name: "Sam"
  }];

  $scope.selectPerson = function(id) {
    $scope.activeClass = id;
    console.log(id);
  };
});
```

CSS:

```
.active-selection {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I only change/remove the class:

```
   function removeClass() {
                    var element = angular.element('#nameInput');
          element.removeClass('nameClass');
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<span ng-class="{'item-text-wrap':viewMore}" ng-click="viewMore= !viewMore"></span>
```

Comment: Add some comments to your answer