# change block style on click

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular-cli

I use Angular CLI, have a menu list. I'd like to change background color of li after click

```
<ul>
   <li class="menu_btn">1</li>
   <li class="menu_btn">2</li>
   <li class="menu_btn">3</li>
   <li class="menu_btn">4</li>
</ul>
```

ts:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  changeColor() {
    let menuButton = document.getElementById("menu_btn");   
  }
```

How I can change the style in ts? Or any way

Comment: I forget (click)="changeColor()"

Comment: `menu_btn` is class not id. you are trying to get an element by id

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754410/2894798

Answer (score 2):

```
 export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {


   constructor() { }

   changeColor() {
      let menuButton = document.getElementsByClassName("menu_btn") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
      menuButton.style.backgroundColor = 'yourColor'; 
  }
```

This will change all the menu_btn classes afer you click

Comment: you mean `getElementsByClass`

Comment: Correct answer :)

Comment: Property 'getElementsByClass' does not exist on type 'Document'.

Comment: @tatamingi  document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf<Element>'.

Comment: try  as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;

Comment: strange and what happens if u loop true them
 for(var i in menuButton ) {
      menuButton [i].backgroundColor = 'yourColor'; 
    }

Comment: Property 'backgroundColor' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Comment: you need a HtmlElement so leave the HtmlCOllectionOF<HtmlElement>

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML there is no ID

use class name instead

```
getElementsByClassName("menu_btn")
```

You can use like this to change style

```
menuButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```