# How to swap between 3 or more classes in Angular targeting only the element clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I would like an element to swap between 3 css classes when clicking it. I have seen other solutions that work when only 2 classes are toggled [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928487/angular-js-how-to-change-an-elements-css-class-on-click-and-to-remove-all-others). These are based on true and false conditions, so it won't work for more than 2 classes.

I got it to swap between the 3 classes, however, click targets all the elements instead of the single element being clicked. **[Here's my code so far](http://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/WpzbNZ)**: `

```
$scope.iconClass = "green";

$scope.iconClicked = function () {
    switch ($scope.iconClass) {
        case "green":
            $scope.iconClass = "red";
            break;
        case "red":
            $scope.iconClass = "blue";
            break;
        default:
            $scope.iconClass = "green";
    }
};`
```

And the html is here: `

```
<li class="item" ng-class="iconClass" ng-click="iconClicked()"> Item 1 <br> </li> 
<li class="item" ng-class="iconClass" ng-click="iconClicked()"> Item 2 <br> </li>
<li class="item" ng-class="iconClass" ng-click="iconClicked()"> Item 3 <br> </li>
```

`

How can I do this **without having to create a different iconClass variable for each different element**? I'm sure there's a simple, elegant solution for this.

Comment: `ng-class="{'red':'iconclass == red', 'blue':'iconClass == blue'}"` - Try this

Comment: You can't use a "local scope class". You're updating a variable that affect three different elements; of course all of them will be toggled.

Answer (score 3):

`ng-class` supports addition of multiple classes, based on logical expressions involving scope variables.

> class="ng-class: expression;"
>
> Expression to eval. The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values.

You can achieve this by `ng-class="{'red':'iconclass == red', 'blue':'iconClass == blue'}"`

You can use the SWAP button to change colors, which is what you are looking for.

A sample example can be found here : http://plnkr.co/edit/lzHkZaBn1RQv24LaxQYT?p=preview

Comment: The idea is to have it work independently in different boxes. If you add an extra box to your code, both will be affected by the button. I'd need each clicked box to affect itself, and only itself.

Comment: You can have a dedicated to `model` for each box. Pass the reference object onto the `ng-click` function, update the class based on the count.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether this will match your requirement but you can create an array and loop through it using `ng-repeat` directive like this

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-class="item.class" ng-click="iconClicked(item)"> {{item.name}} <br> </li>
```

scope `items` array

```
$scope.items = [{"name":"Item 1","class":"black"},{"name":"Item 1","class":"black"},{"name":"Item 1","class":"black"}]
```

additional css class.

```
.black{
  color: black;
}
```

change the onclick function like this

```
$scope.iconClicked = function (item) {
        $scope.items =  $scope.items.map(function(o){          
          o.class = "black"
          return o;
        } ) 
         item.class = "red";
};
```

Note that this will color the selected text red and others will be black 
'

[Demo](http://codepen.io/sachila/pen/gmepbe)

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a custom directive with isolate scope to make it happen.

Does anyone knows a better idea? Would be more than welcome.

[Here's the new code](http://codepen.io/blindpupil/pen/WpzbNZ?editors=1010)

```
function ListItem() {
  var ddo = {
    template: '<li class="item" ng-class="iconClass" ng-click="iconClicked()"> Item 1 (isolate) <br> </li>',
    scope: {
      items: '<'
    },
    controller: 'MyController'
  };
  return ddo;
}
```